# No visible @interface for 'JSQSystemSoundPlayer' error

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I just added the files:

```
JSQSystemSoundPlayer.h
JSQSystemSoundPlayer.m
```

into my project and it rose the next error:

```
No visible @interface for 'JSQSystemSoundPlayer' declares the selector 'playAlertSoundWithFilename:fileExtension:'
```

I searched a lot but could'n find the solution. Can anyone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the declaration of the method

```
- (void)playAlertSoundWithFilename:(NSString *)filename
                 fileExtension:(NSString *)fileExtension
                    completion:(nullable JSQSystemSoundPlayerCompletionBlock)completionBlock;
```

You're missing completion block, there is no such method with only two parameters

Here is example how to use it

```
[[JSQSystemSoundPlayer sharedPlayer] playSoundWithFilename:@"mySoundFile"
                                             fileExtension:kJSQSystemSoundTypeAIF
                                                completion:^{
                                                  // completion block code
                                                }];
```

---

#### Edit: As per comments

If you look at the declaration of [`playSoundWithFilename: fileExtension: completion:`](https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQSystemSoundPlayer/blob/develop/Source/JSQSystemSoundPlayer.h) method you will find

```
@param completionBlock A block called after the sound has stopped playing.
```

Which means do whatever you want to do after the sound has stopped playing. If you don't want to do anything then either you can pass `nil` or empty block as above

Comment: Your solution worked...so thank you for that, but I don't understand what should go in the "completion block code" area. Can you lend some guidance?

Comment: i have added jsqMessageViewController and then it shows no jsqsoundsystemplayer file.....Then what i have to add.Only 2 files JSQSystemSoundPlayer.h and JSQSystemSoundPlayer.m i have to add or entire JSQSystemSoundPlayer folder.....suggest me @inder

Comment: @Raghunath it's `JSQSystemSoundPlayer` not `jsqsoundsystemplayer` or `JSQSoundSystemPlayer`

Comment: Just i have added `JSQSystemSoundPlayer.h` and `JSQSystemSoundPlayer.m` into my project.But it shows `JSQSystemSoundPlayer/JSQSystemSoundPlayer.h not found` in a category file  JSQSystemSoundPlayer+JSQMessages.h.

Comment: @InderKumarRathore there??

Comment: Please ask a new question for the same on Stackoverflow and explain what are you doing and what's your problem.